# Make table headers stay on screen while scrolling table (idea below)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, scrollbar, tabular

I have a table, it includes normal header row on the top and on the left side header column. And I need to show both headers fixed on the screen, always visible, while the spreadsheet is scrolled.

The problem is that I have two header areas. If it was one header, it would be resolved with divs, but here I need some other logic.

So if you scroll horizontally, left header stays on the screen while top header is scrolled together with the spreadsheet. If you scroll vertically, top header stays on the screen while left header is scrolled together with spreadsheet.

Comment: http://docs.handsontable.com/0.19.0/demo-fixed-rows-and-columns.html

Answer (score 2):

Is [this](http://codepen.io/jgx/pen/wiIGc) what you are looking for?

```js
;(function($) {
   $.fn.fixMe = function() {
      return this.each(function() {
         var $this = $(this),
            $t_fixed;
         function init() {
            $this.wrap('<div class="container" />');
            $t_fixed = $this.clone();
            $t_fixed.find("tbody").remove().end().addClass("fixed").insertBefore($this);
            resizeFixed();
         }
         function resizeFixed() {
            $t_fixed.find("th").each(function(index) {
               $(this).css("width",$this.find("th").eq(index).outerWidth()+"px");
            });
         }
         function scrollFixed() {
            var offset = $(this).scrollTop(),
            tableOffsetTop = $this.offset().top,
            tableOffsetBottom = tableOffsetTop + $this.height() - $this.find("thead").height();
            if(offset < tableOffsetTop || offset > tableOffsetBottom)
               $t_fixed.hide();
            else if(offset >= tableOffsetTop && offset <= tableOffsetBottom && $t_fixed.is(":hidden"))
               $t_fixed.show();
         }
         $(window).resize(resizeFixed);
         $(window).scroll(scrollFixed);
         init();
      });
   };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("table").fixMe();
   $(".up").click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
   }, 2000);
 });
});
```

```css
body{
  font:1.2em normal Arial,sans-serif;
  color:#34495E;
}

h1{
  text-align:center;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  letter-spacing:-2px;
  font-size:2.5em;
  margin:20px 0;
}

.container{
  width:90%;
  margin:auto;
}

table{
  border-collapse:collapse;
  width:100%;
}

.blue{
  border:2px solid #1ABC9C;
}

.blue thead{
  background:#1ABC9C;
}

.purple{
  border:2px solid #9B59B6;
}

.purple thead{
  background:#9B59B6;
}

thead{
  color:white;
}

th,td{
  text-align:center;
  padding:5px 0;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even){
  background:#ECF0F1;
}

tbody tr:hover{
background:#BDC3C7;
  color:#FFFFFF;
}

.fixed{
  top:0;
  position:fixed;
  width:auto;
  display:none;
  border:none;
}

.scrollMore{
  margin-top:600px;
}

.up{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<h1>&darr; SCROLL &darr;</h1>
<table class="blue">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Colonne 1</th>
      <th>Colonne 2</th>
      <th>Colonne 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h1 class="scrollMore">&darr; SCROLL MORE &darr;</h1>
<table class="purple">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Colonne 1</th>
      <th>Colonne 2</th>
      <th>Colonne 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<h1 class="up scrollMore">&uarr; UP &uarr;</h1>
```

Comment: To make sure the fixed header is initially hidden if appropriate, call `scrollFixed()` at the end of `init()`.